# Black box instead of images on Galaxy Note 2 after OpenGL texture loading

Tags: android, opengl-es

I work on panorama player for android, and have really wierd situation on specific device Galaxy Note 2.

After of couple of cycles of loading/unloading opengl textures i got situation like this:

[image: Font dropped]

Images that manipulated trough resources by setting indexes of R.drawable and fonts become corrupted, and no OutOfMemory errors, exceptions, OpenGL erros etc - and heap sitting under 30-35mb.

I don't have any ideas what's going wrong and where, I will be very grateful for any thoughts and tips about origin of the problem.

Comment: Some code would be nice.

Comment: hm i really don't understand what portion of code to insert, i use heavily modified PanoramaGL (http://code.google.com/p/panoramagl-android/) and there is really a lot of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got exactly the same problem. I solved it by turning OFF hardware acceleration for the whole application in the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

So the main reason of this problem is usage of GL texture memory used by hardware acceleration, there is no OutOfMemory because application can utilize almost all device memory for textures. But texture memory also used for hardware accelerated rendering of views, fonts ets.

so the cure is disable hardware acceleration or limit usage, or lower fragmentation of texture memory.